# Javascript code is not working

Tags: javascript, html

How can I amend the code so that when I select a option from the first drop down menu the second drop down menu becomes editable otherwise the second drop-down menu should be read only, and if the option in the first drop down menu is "default" then the second drop down menu should be read only.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function mySecondFunction() {
    document.getElementById("mySelection").disabled = false;
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<form action="">
<select name="cars" onload="mySecondFunction()">
<option value="default">default</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<br>
<select disabled name="cars" id="mySelection">
<option value="Action1">Volvo</option>
<option value="Action2">Saab</option>
<option value="Action3">Fiat</option>
<option value="Action4">Audi</option>
</select>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the capitals:

```
document.getElementById("MySelection").disabled = false;
<select disabled name="cars" id="mySelection">
```

The first is with "M" and the seccond with "m"

Comment: see not working - the second drop down menu should become editable after you have selected an option in first drop down menu

Answer (score 1):

You have misspelled `MySelection` with `mySelection`

In the JS you have `document.getElementById("MySelection") // notice the uppercase M`

and in the HTML you have `id="mySelection"`

Also set the second select to false when the window loads and add a `onChange` event to the first select that will set the second event to enabled/true... it this what you want?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("mySelection").disabled = true;
};

function mySecondFunction() {
    document.getElementById("mySelection").disabled = false;
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<form action="">
<select name="cars" onchange="mySecondFunction()">
<option value="default">default</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<br>
<select name="cars" id="mySelection">
<option value="Action1">Volvo</option>
<option value="Action2">Saab</option>
<option value="Action3">Fiat</option>
<option value="Action4">Audi</option>
</select>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

You may want to set the second select back to disabled if the user selects 'default' in the first menu after changing the value

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript selectors are case sensitive. Your mistake is at `mySelection` id:

```
document.getElementById("MySelection").disabled = false;
<select disabled name="cars" id="mySelection">
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use that inside body tag .
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5m42y574/)

```
<head>


</head>
<body onload="mySecondFunction()">

<form action="">
<select name="cars" >
<option value="default">default</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<br>
<select disabled name="cars" id="mySelection">
<option value="Action1">Volvo</option>
<option value="Action2">Saab</option>
<option value="Action3">Fiat</option>
<option value="Action4">Audi</option>
</select>
</form>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function mySecondFunction() {
alert("aaa");
    document.getElementById("mySelection").disabled = false;
}

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out you mispelled the id of the second `<select>` but also you used the wrong event, `onchange` is what you want instead of `onload`.

```js
function mySecondFunction() {
  document.getElementById('mySelection').disabled = false;    
}
```

```html
<form action="">
    <select name="cars" onchange="mySecondFunction();">
        <option value="default">default</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    
    <br />
        
    <select disabled="disabled" name="cars" id="mySelection">
        <option value="Action1">Volvo</option>
        <option value="Action2">Saab</option>
        <option value="Action3">Fiat</option>
        <option value="Action4">Audi</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

But consider using jQuery and attach your events in javascript instead of having them stored in html.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Replace

```
document.getElementById("mySelection").disabled = false;
```

with this

```
document.getElementById("mySelection").removeAttribute('disabled');
```

Also, you may want to change

```
onload="mySecondFunction()"
```

with this:

```
onchange="mySecondFunction()"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove the disable in a specific value like (Saab)

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ez5jhgqm/)
note: put the script in b4 the head tag

```
    function mySecondFunction()
{
 var ddl = document.getElementById("1");
 var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
    if (selectedValue == "saab")
   {
    document.getElementById("mySelection").disabled = false;
   }else {
    document.getElementById("mySelection").disabled = true;
   }
}

<form action="">
    <select id="1" name="cars" onchange="mySecondFunction()">
        <option value="default">default</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>

    <br />

    <select disabled="disabled" name="cars" id="mySelection">
        <option value="Action1">Volvo</option>
        <option value="Action2">Saab</option>
        <option value="Action3">Fiat</option>
        <option value="Action4">Audi</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**UPDATE**
[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kv4p5u3t/)

```
function mySecondFunction()
{
 var ddl = document.getElementById("1");
 var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
    if (selectedValue == "default")
   {
    document.getElementById("mySelection").disabled = true;
   }else {
    document.getElementById("mySelection").disabled = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: How do you do it so that if its default then the second drop down remains disabled, whereas if its any other value other then default the second drop down should be editable

Comment: Just change the change values to default and switch false and true






    
`function mySecondFunction()
    {
 var ddl = document.getElementById("1");
 var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
    if (selectedValue == "default")
   {
    document.getElementById("mySelection").disabled = true;
   }else {
    document.getElementById("mySelection").disabled = false;
   }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Change onload to onchange.

```
<select name="cars" onchange="mySecondFunction();">
```